# GetPastEvents From Web3 - Return Zero . instead Number of transactions?

Tags: web3js

I tried This Code With The **GetPastEvents** to get Transactions from a smart contract. but the console return 0 . and the error is Null.

Check the code below . ***Help me fix this please!!***

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/......')


const abi = [ABI_CODE_FROM_SMARTCONTRACT]
const address = '0x95dAaaB98046846bF4B2853e23cba236fa394A31'

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)


contract.getPastEvents('allEvents', {fromBlock: 9851116, toBlock:'latest'}, (err, events) => {
    console.log(events.length)
})
```

Comment: It is not possible to help you, as your question does not have context. What events, which Ehereum network, and so on. I suggest you edit your question and add more background, context and detail.

Comment: okey Check it now. I follow a tutorial i did the same. i change the AllEvents To allEvents, this code must show a number of transactions from the block to latest.!

Comment: What smart contract is it? Can share the link and then check on EtherScan that the smart contract has any events or transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're connecting to ropsten:

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/......')
```

There is no contract at [ropsten address 0x95dAaaB98046846bF4B2853e23cba236fa394A31](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x95dAaaB98046846bF4B2853e23cba236fa394A31).

But there **is** one at [mainnet address 0x95dAaaB98046846bF4B2853e23cba236fa394A31](https://etherscan.io/address/0x95dAaaB98046846bF4B2853e23cba236fa394A31).

So what you really want is probably to connect to mainnet instead:

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/......')
```